# Angular2 with Rx.subject not refreshing the view

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-changedetection

Probably I'm missing some Angular2 concept about Change Detection.

I've read about NgZones and ChangeDetectionStrategy but none seemed to solve my problem.

The case is I have a external module where I store my Observables and consume them in some components, when one of the components changes something into the service, it propagates to the other components.

I wrote a Plunker to help to express my problem

http://plnkr.co/edit/ieHnm0ikBe4BR5w6O1XE?p=preview

In there, I have the `src/MyService.ts` where I simulate an `Subject` with constant data change using a `setInterval`.

The `Subject` is consumed in the `src/app.ts` and its value only get rendered when you click a button with a empty click handler.

**src/MyService.ts**

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

let global = {};

// The Observable
global.subject = new Rx.Subject();

// Updates value every second
setInterval(() => global.subject.next(Date.now()), 1000);

export var Global = global;
```

**src/app.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {Global} from './myService'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="clickMe()">Click me</button>
      <p>Current time: {{subject | async}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  public subject = Global.subject;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  public clickMe () {
    console.log("I'm just a click event that do nothing");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is your service like that? All what's happening there is out of angular2 zone

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what you are looking for.

### <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7BYNTlAYwoMWIwDkFlWe?p=preview)</kbd>

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectorRef} from 'angular2/core'
import {Global} from './myService'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="clickMe()">Click me</button>
      <p>Current time: {{subject | async}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})

export class App {

  public subject = Global.subject;

  constructor(public ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.name = 'Angular2';

    setInterval(() => {
                this.ref.detectChanges();
              }, 1000);
  }

  public clickMe () {
    console.log("I'm just a click event that do nothing");
  }
}
```

---

You may also want to look at this.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {GlobalSR} from './myService'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [GlobalSR],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <button (click)="clickMe()">Click me</button>
      <p>Current time: {{subject | async}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})

export class App {

  public subject;

  constructor(public globalSR: GlobalSR) {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.subject = globalSR.global.subject;

  }

  public clickMe () {
    console.log("I'm just a click event that do nothing");
  }
}
```

### <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ilFCiptqOb2D4KYZnKit?p=preview)</kbd>

maybe this help you if you like global share
[angular2-global-service-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465533/angular2-global-service-provider)

I do not know what you want to do. I hope it will help you and sorry for my English