# How to register one instance of service in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

How to register one instance of service in Angular 4 - everywhere in application?

I need to have singleton object of custom service.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465533/angular2-global-service-provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share on singleton across multiple modules, you have to implement `forRoot()`. Otherwise, everytime the module with your service is imported, a new instance of your service will be created.

```
@NgModule({
  ...
})
export class MyModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [MyService]
    };
  }
}
```

Import the module once in your application with `.forRoot()` (usually in your AppModule). In all other modules, you can just import the module without `forRoot()`.

Injecting it in a component just as regular, without specifiing a provider at the decorator.

```
constructor(myService: MyService) { }
```

Comment: How to use in component?

Answer (score 2):

You should provide GlobalService at bootstrap.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [GlobalService])

@Component({
  providers: [], // yes
  // providers: [GlobalService], // NO.
})
class AppComponent {
  constructor(private gs: GlobalService) {
    // gs is instance of GlobalService created at bootstrap
  }
}
```

This way GlobalService will be a singleton.

check this link : [Angular2 global service provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465533/angular2-global-service-provider)

Answer (score 1):

Generate a service with angular-cli (if you have it)

```
ng g s DebugService
```

That should create a new file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DebugService {

  constructor() {}

}
```

Add it to root module, it might be app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [DebugService],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then wherever you need this service, you inject it 
by importing it

```
import {DebugService} from './debug.service';
```

then by declaring it in the constructor of a component

```
constructor(private debugService: DebugService) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the provider in the root module(ex: AppModeule) or import the module which the provider belong to in the root module. Then you can use the provider as a singleton object.

Hope this helps you.